# IP Camera not working in HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, webcam, ip-camera

I want to show the video I get from the IP camera on the HTML page. I can show the video camera as modified in its own IP.

[image: Camera's own IP Page]

I sense color from the camera view via a script. I need to transfer the view to the HTML page I created. My HTML5 code:

```
<video id="video" style="width:600px;max-width:100%;" src="http://192.168.1.90:8001/" controls="" autoplay>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video>
```

My HTML page looks like this

[image: My HTML page]

I can get the webcam view with this code without *src* tag. Is there a way to transfer the IP camera view to my HTML page.

Thanks for your helps...

Comment: Sorry, but it is totally unclear what your actual issue is.

Comment: You _might_ refer to an issue with IP ranges and address being allowed to access the images or not. But that is only a very wild guess. You will need to be much more precise in your question. So: what is it that does not work? What do your http servers error log files say? what does your browsers console say?

Comment: I can not get the IP camera view on the HTML page with the above code. This is my issue. Is there an another code I can do?

Comment: Did you even understand the questions I asked?

Comment: what happend if you open this link on the browser? http://192.168.1.90:8001

Comment: I understand @arkascha. But I checked all of them.

Comment: And, what is the result of that "check"?

Comment: When I open the link in the browser, page redirect view screen IP camera. @AriDjemana

Comment: well you need to check console and see what is wrong. right click on chrome. and chose inspect. then select network tab. then refresh the page. check this link for more information. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLetk.jpg like this?